# Curl return 404, but 200 with Postman

Tags: php, curl, postman

I have a curl call to API on localhost. The call worked before, but now I get a 404 error. Now, if I run the same query in Postman it works fine all time. I can't understand why.

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8;'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method); //POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_base.$url.$token);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    
   $curl_log = fopen("curl.txt", 'a'); // open file for READ and write
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $curl_log);

    if(!empty($data)) {
       if($method == "POST" || $method == "PUT") {
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data); //(json)
       }
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $aux = curl_exec($ch);

    rewind($curl_log);
   $output = fread($curl_log, 2048);
   echo "<pre>" . print_r($output, 1) . "</pre>";
   fclose($curl_log);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
       $error_msg = curl_error($ch); //404
    }
```

*Sorry, but the URL contain a private token*

Postman Request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://PRIVATEURL' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"data":{"id":null,"name":"Solo","supplierId":null,"rooms":3,"livingRoom":null,"bathrooms":2,"toilets":1,"totalBeds":6,"supportedLosRates":false,"space":"190","spaceUnit":"SQ_M","persons":6,"childs":null,"latitude":48.8678000000000025693225325085222721099853515625,"longitude":2.35024999999999995026200849679298698902130126953125,"altId":"50","currency":"EUR","location":{"postalCode":"75002","country":"FR","region":"Paris","city":"Paris","street":"16-28 Rue du Caire","zipCode9":null},"propertyType":"PCT3","attributesWithQuantity":[],"notes":{"description":{"texts":[{"language":"ES","value":"Con el Palacio del El\u00edseo como vecino, ad\u00e9ntrese en el lujo y la sofisticaci\u00f3n franceses en el coraz\u00f3n del 8e Arrondissement en Par\u00eds. Ubicado en un edificio aristocr\u00e1tico de 1858, este apartamento de Haussmann representa una pieza de la historia representativa del \"arte de vivir\" \u00e0 la Fran\u00e7aise en el siglo XIX. Art de Vivre \u00c9lys\u00e9e ofrece un sentimiento de castillo para los viajeros epic\u00fareos que disfrutan de grandes espacios interiores mientras est\u00e1n rodeados de las mejores cosas de la vida, tanto en casa como a la puerta.Este alquiler de vacaciones exhibe antig\u00fcedades que han sido cuidadosamente coleccionadas, yuxtapuestas con mobiliario contempor\u00e1neo y equipamiento actualizado. Salga al balc\u00f3n de hierro forjado de treinta pies de largo y contemple la escena del tr\u00e1fico y los peatones de abajo. Los extras de este apartamento incluyen conexi\u00f3n Wi-Fi, una cafetera espresso, TV v\u00eda sat\u00e9lite y un sistema de sonido Sonos.Con su decoraci\u00f3n grandiosa, su serie de recepciones espaciosas con techos altos y 15 ventanas del piso al techo disfrutan de la secuencia de patrones de claroscuros moldeados por la luz cambiante del d\u00eda. Admire las cornisas finamente trabajadas, las molduras talladas, los frisos delicadamente esculpidos, los pisos de parquet de espiga de roble, las chimeneas de m\u00e1rmol, el bronce y los candelabros de cristal. Disfrute de una comida suculenta en el comedor formal y la cocina bien equipada con vistas a un patio con establos antiguos."},{"language":"EN","value":"With the Elys\u00e9e Palace as a neighbor, immerse yourself in French luxury and sophistication in the heart of the 8th Arrondissement in Paris. Housed in an aristocratic building from 1858, this Haussmann apartment represents a piece of history representative of the \"art of living\" \u00e0 la Fran\u00e7aise in the 19th century. Art de Vivre \u00c9lys\u00e9e offers a castle feeling for epicurean travelers who enjoy large indoor spaces while surrounded by the best things in life, both at home and at the door. This vacation rental exhibits antiques that have been carefully collected, juxtaposed with contemporary furniture and updated equipment. Exit to the thirty-foot-long wrought-iron balcony and watch the traffic scene and the pedestrians below. Extras in this apartment include Wi-Fi, an espresso machine, satellite TV and a Sonos sound system. With its grandiose d\u00e9cor, its series of spacious receptions with high ceilings and 15 floor-to-ceiling windows enjoy the sequence of chiaroscuro patterns molded by the changing light of the day. Admire the finely worked cornices, carved moldings, delicately sculpted friezes, oak herringbone floors, marble fireplaces, bronze and crystal chandeliers. Enjoy a succulent meal in the formal dining room and the well-equipped kitchen overlooking a courtyard with old stables. "},{"language":"FR","value":"Avec l'\''Elys\u00e9e en tant que voisin, plongez dans le luxe et la sophistication fran\u00e7aise au c\u0153ur du 8\u00e8me arrondissement de Paris. Install\u00e9 dans un b\u00e2timent aristocratique de 1858, cet appartement haussmannien repr\u00e9sente une pi\u00e8ce d'\''histoire repr\u00e9sentative de \u00abl'\''art de vivre\u00bb \u00e0 la Fran\u00e7aise au XIXe si\u00e8cle. Art de Vivre \u00c9lys\u00e9e offre un sentiment de ch\u00e2teau pour les voyageurs \u00e9picuriens qui aiment les grands espaces int\u00e9rieurs tout en \u00e9tant entour\u00e9 par les choses de la vie, \u00e0 la fois \u00e0 la maison et \u00e0 la porte. Cette location de vacances pr\u00e9sente des antiquit\u00e9s qui ont \u00e9t\u00e9 soigneusement collect\u00e9es, juxtapos\u00e9es avec des meubles contemporains et des \u00e9quipements mis \u00e0 jour. Sortez sur le balcon en fer forg\u00e9 de trente pieds de long et observez la circulation et les pi\u00e9tons en contrebas. Les extras dans cet appartement comprennent une connexion Wi-Fi, une machine \u00e0 expresso, la t\u00e9l\u00e9vision par satellite et un syst\u00e8me de son Sonos. Avec son d\u00e9cor grandiose, sa s\u00e9rie d'\''accueil avec de hauts plafonds et des fen\u00eatres 15 du sol au plafond b\u00e9n\u00e9ficient des motifs s\u00e9quence de clair-obscur en forme par la lumi\u00e8re du jour changeant. Admirez les corniches finement travaill\u00e9es, les moulures sculpt\u00e9es, les frises d\u00e9licatement sculpt\u00e9es, les planchers en ch\u00eane \u00e0 chevrons, les chemin\u00e9es en marbre, les lustres en bronze et en cristal. Profitez d'\''un succulent repas dans la salle \u00e0 manger formelle et la cuisine bien \u00e9quip\u00e9e donnant sur une cour avec de vieilles \u00e9curies. "},{"language":"IT","value":"Con l'\''Elys\u00e9e Palace come vicino di casa, immergiti nel lusso francese e nella raffinatezza nel cuore dell'\''8 \u00b0 arrondissement a Parigi. Ospitato in un edificio aristocratico dal 1858, questo appartamento Haussmann rappresenta un pezzo di storia rappresentante dell '\''\"arte di vivere\" \u00e0 la Fran\u00e7aise nel 19 \u00b0 secolo. L'\''Art de Vivre \u00c9lys\u00e9e offre un'\''atmosfera da castello per viaggiatori epicurei che amano i grandi spazi interni mentre sono circondati dalle cose migliori della vita, sia a casa che alla porta. Questa casa vacanze espone oggetti d'\''antiquariato raccolti con cura, giustapposti a mobili contemporanei e attrezzature aggiornate. Esci sul balcone di ferro battuto lungo trenta metri e osserva la scena del traffico e i pedoni sottostanti. Gli extra di questo appartamento includono la connessione Wi-Fi, una macchina per caff\u00e8 espresso, una TV satellitare e un sistema audio Sonos. Con il suo arredamento grandioso, la sua serie di ampi ricevimenti con soffitti alti e 15 finestre dal pavimento al soffitto godono della sequenza di modelli in chiaroscuro modellati dalla luce mutevole del giorno. Ammira le cornici finemente lavorate, le modanature scolpite, i fregi delicatamente scolpiti, i pavimenti in parquet di quercia a spina di pesce, i caminetti in marmo, i lampadari in bronzo e cristallo. Goditi un pasto succulento nella sala da pranzo formale e nella cucina ben attrezzata che si affaccia su un cortile con vecchie stalle. "},{"language":"PT","value":"Com o Elys\u00e9e Palace como vizinho, mergulhe no luxo franc\u00eas e na sofistica\u00e7\u00e3o no cora\u00e7\u00e3o do 8\u00ba Arrondissement, em Paris. Abrigado num edif\u00edcio aristocr\u00e1tico de 1858, este apartamento Haussmann representa uma hist\u00f3ria hist\u00f3rica representativa da \"arte de viver\" \u00e0 la Fran\u00e7aise no s\u00e9culo XIX. Art de Vivre \u00c9lys\u00e9e oferece um sentimento de castelo para os viajantes epic\u00faricos que desfrutam de grandes espa\u00e7os interiores, cercados pelas melhores coisas da vida, tanto em casa quanto na porta. Este aluguer de f\u00e9rias exibe antiguidades cuidadosamente coletadas, justapostas com m\u00f3veis contempor\u00e2neos e equipamentos atualizados. Saia da bala de ferro forjado de trinta metros de comprimento e assista a cena do tr\u00e2nsito e os pedestres abaixo. Os extras deste apartamento incluem Wi-Fi, m\u00e1quina de caf\u00e9 expresso, TV via sat\u00e9lite e sistema de som Sonos. Com sua decora\u00e7\u00e3o grandiosa, sua s\u00e9rie de recep\u00e7\u00f5es espa\u00e7osas com tectos altos e 15 janelas do ch\u00e3o ao teto desfrutam da sequ\u00eancia de padr\u00f5es de claroscuro moldados pela luz passageira do dia. Admire as cornijas finamente trabalhadas, molduras esculpidas, frisos delicadamente esculpidos, pisos de madeira de carvalho, lareiras de m\u00e1rmore, lustres de bronze e de cristal. Desfrute de uma refei\u00e7\u00e3o suculenta na sala de jantar formal e da cozinha bem equipada com vista para um p\u00e1tio com est\u00e1bulos antigos. "}]},"houseRules":{"texts":[]}},"bedroomConfiguration":null,"policy":{"internetPolicy":{"accessInternet":false,"kindOfInternet":null,"availableInternet":null},"parkingPolicy":{"accessParking":false,"locatedParking":null,"privateParking":false,"necessaryReservationParking":null},"petPolicy":{"allowedPets":"NotAllowed","chargePets":null},"childrenAllowed":false,"smokingAllowed":false},"checkInTime":"07:00:00","checkInToTime":null,"checkOutTime":"15:00:00"}}'
```

Output file 'curl.txt':

- Trying *PRIVATEIP*...
- TCP_NODELAY set
- Connected to *PRIVATEURL* port 443 (#0)
- ALPN, offering http/1.1
- Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: C:\mamp\cacert.pem
  CApath: none
- SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
- ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
- Server certificate:
- subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=*.*PRIVATESERVER*
- start date: Nov 22 16:32:04 2018 GMT
- expire date: Jan 13 14:19:55 2021 GMT
- subjectAltName: host "*PRIVATESERVER*" matched cert's "*.*PRIVATESERVER*"
- issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
- SSL certificate verify ok.

> POST /xml/services/rest/supplierapi/*PRIVATEURL* HTTP/1.1
> Host: *PRIVATEURL*
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8;
> Content-Length: 1157
> Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

- We are completely uploaded and fine
- The requested URL returned error: 404
- stopped the pause stream!
- Closing connection 0

Comment: cURL has many options to help when dealing with SSL connections - such as `CURLOPT_CAINFO`, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` - [download a copy of cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) and configure your curl request to use that file with suitable options set for the above parameters

Comment: I added a similar certificate through php.ini.
curl.cainfo="C:\mamp\cacert.pem" 
openssl.cafile="C:\mamp\cacert.pem". The code was working until this morning